# Nginx as web server render index html with variables

Tags: nginx, indexing, ssi, server-side-includes

Issue: I need to modify the response which is HTML. Need to inject data attribute into the response body.

The data attribute value would be the query param/post params.

Having Nginx as a webserver. How can we achieve this?

I checked already the nginx+lua. But is there any other approach? Also would SSI solve this problem? If yes then how can we get the query param and post value from nginx

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

You are exposing yourself to XSS attacks but it should be possible with the [ngx_http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html). To access query string parameter `foo` use `$arg_foo`.

So something like this:

```
location / {
    sub_filter '##NAME##'  $arg_foo;
}
```

If you call your site with `?foo=Hello` it will replace `##NAME##` in your HTML with `Hello`.

In general however it's a terrible idea to let outside things (like querystring parameters) directly pass into your HTML!